# Dragging not working for react-use-gesture

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-experience

For some reason, I just cannot get the most basic example of react-use-gesture to work. What I am trying to do is just have a square follow my mouse location when you drag it. I copy-pasted the example from their documentation multiple times (https://github.com/pmndrs/react-use-gesture) and still cannot get it to work. I just don't understand it anymore. I created a stackblitz to show you my code. What am I still doing wrong?

Stackblitz with code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mg2u8p?file=src/Square.js

I will also include the most relevant code here:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useSpring, animated } from "react-spring";
import { useDrag } from "react-use-gesture";

const Square = () => {
  const [{ x, y }, set] = useSpring(() => ({ x: 0, y: 0 }));
  const bind = useDrag(({ down, movement: [mx, my] }) => {
    set({ x: down ? mx : 0, y: down ? my : 0 });
  });

  return (
    <animated.div
      {...bind()}
      className="Square"
      style={{ x, y, touchAction: "none" }}
    />
  );
};

export default Square;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a version problem.

Your example uses code for `react-spring` version `9+`, but the version of `react-spring` you're using in the example is `8.0.27`.

The example the documentation gives for version `8` is this:

```
import { useSpring, animated } from 'react-spring'
import { useDrag } from 'react-use-gesture'

function PullRelease() {
  const [{ xy }, set] = useSpring(() => ({ xy: [0, 0] }))
  // Set the drag hook and define component movement based on gesture data
  const bind = useDrag(({ down, movement }) => {
    set({ xy: down ? movement : [0, 0] })
  })
  // Bind it to a component
  return (
    <animated.div
      {...bind()}
      style={{
        transform: xy.interpolate((x, y) => `translate3d(${x}px, ${y}px, 0)`),
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

So in your case you would only need to change `PullRelease` to `Square` and add `className="Square"` to the `animated.div` like you had it in your question.

---

For both the documentation on the `v8` and `v9` implementation of this using React UseGesture see [this](https://use-gesture.netlify.app/docs/#simple-example).

If you want to use the `v9` version, you currently need to install `react-spring@next` according to the documentation (see previous link).